# Powershell regex to match letters

Tags: regex, powershell

Need advice on the formatting of a regex in powershell.

I have some AD users which all have custom attributes "A", "AA", "B", "BB" and up to 5 letters in length, ranging from A-Z.

So i want to find which user have the attribute "ABAA" and then create a variable that will be used to locate which path to choose.
E.g. user with attribute "AA" will go into the "A" Organizational Unit.

```
if ($customattribute -match '^[a-z]{2}[^a-z]')
```

I am guessing this just matches random letters. How will the formatting be for "AA" or "BBB"?

Comment: The regex you could use would be ^(ABAA).
Similar for the other possibilities.

Comment: Your explanation is very unclear. What kind of pattern are you looking for? What exactly is the relationship between attribute value and OU?

Comment: The users customattribute define which OU they should be placed in. So user with value ABAA is placed in OU_A - SubOU_B - SubOU_A - SubOU_A.

Comment: In that case I would create a hashtable mapping the possible strings to the corresponding OU paths and then simply do a lookup in that hashtable.

Comment: Please show your current code. Note that to match `AA` or `BBB` at the start of the string, you may use `"^(?:AA|BBB)"` and if you need case sensitive matching use `-cmatch` instead of `-match`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex fits your description of the data better:

```
if ($customattribute -match '^[A-Z]{2,5}$')
```

Your regex will match two lowercase letters at the start of the string and then another character that can be anything except a lowercase letter - doesn't sound like that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this would best suit my needs

```
if ($customattribute -match '^A[A-Z]')
```

Then i get all users with customattribute like AA, AB and ACA.

```
AA
AB
ACA
```

But how can i limit the regex to only 2 letters, so that i get all 2 letter combinations starting with A?

@edit

Well i figured it out:

```
if ($customattribute -match '^A[A-Z]{1}$') # 2 letters

if ($customattribute -match '^A[A-Z]{2}$') # 3 letters
```